# Check email address is unique to the system

Tags: javascript, jquery, database, jsp

I have a jsp page where the user enters their email address and password. I am storing the email and password in a database. My problem is that I want to enter the data only if it is unique to the system. I mean the email address should be unique. Duplicates are not allowed. I cannot change the database where the email field is not unique.

Thanks
Romi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just query database table for entered e-mail, if it returns a result then do not insert that e-mail and warn user that he should enter something else.

Comment: what is the return type of null ??

Comment: if you are using jdbc, you can test the ResultSet that returns from Statement.executeQuery(...). if ResultSet.next() returns false for the first time then it means that select query returns an empty set.

I just used class names, you need to instantiate objects of that classes in order to use.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery%28java.lang.String%29

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next%28%29

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple: just try to find given email in database, if it exists it means duplicate. You can create dedicated controller that does this check and make AJAX call to that controller from client side, to make you application more responsive;